# Converting a .xlsx file to .csv using Syncfusion.XlsIO - Null reference exception

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, syncfusion

I have a file in blob storage that is in .xslx format and I am trying to convert it to .csv format using Syncfusion.XlsIO Nuget package.

I have tried the following:

```
        private async Task ConvertExcelToCsv()
        {
            var fileName = await _fileStore.GetContainerFileAsync(AppSettingsConstants.FileNames.Container, "myfile.xlsx");

            using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
            {
                var application = excelEngine.Excel;
                var workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(fileName.Name);
                var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];
                worksheet.SaveAs("myfile.csv", ",");
            }
        }
```

When I debug, the fileName is retrieved successfully, but the application breaks on `using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())` with a NullReferenceException error.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Show the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, it turned out I was missing a reference to `System.Drawing` nuget

Answer (score 2):

The way you can do it is defined here: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9098/how-to-export-excel-data-to-csv-file
Most likely, you would need to install from NuGet not only `Syncfusion.XlsIO.WinForms` , but also `System.Drawing.Common` and `System.Security.Permissions`.

This code worked:

```
            try
            {

                //Initialize ExcelEngine
                using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
                {
                    //Initialize Application
                    IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;

                    //Set default version for application
                    application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2013;

                    //Open a workbook to be export as CSV
                    IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(@"E:\Users\Public\Documents\" + "ExcelFile.xlsx");

                    //Accessing first worksheet in the workbook
                    IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

                    //Save the workbook to csv format
                    worksheet.SaveAs("Output.csv", ",");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                throw;
            }
```

Make sure you have permission to access the Excel file. Usually, it helps if you test it with files which are saved on another drive than on which Windows is installed (e.g. E:\, if Windows is on C:\).